# Process HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to remove all instances of a .class in an html.

remove class "s"

```
 remove <span class="s">some text</span> in html
```

Output

```
 remove some text in html
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: grab the parent and replace the innerHTML

Comment: Are you using any libraries or just vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: I think he's asking how to conditionally strip HTML from text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plain JavaScript solution. It might look a bit long at first sight, but it simply does what you want:

```
function moveElements(root) {
  var parent = root.parentNode,
      e = root.firstChild;
  while (e != null) {
    var next = e.nextSibling;
    parent.insertBefore(e, root);
    e = next;
  }
  parent.removeChild(root);
}

function removeClass(root, name) {
  var e = root.firstChild;
  while (e != null) {
    var next = e.nextSibling;
    if (e.nodeType == 1) { // element node
      if (e.className == name)
        moveElements(e);   // move children outside this element
      else
        removeClass(e, name);  // else recursively scan this element
    }
    e = next;
  }
}
```

`removeClass` recursively scans elements looking for the specified class, and if found, calls `moveElements`, which moves the children outside and removes the original element. To run it through the entire document, removing the class `s` (from your example), call it like this:

```
removeClass(document.documentElement, 's');
```

Here's a [working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ipaze).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove it from just this class. Here's how to keep just the text:

```
$(".s").each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

[Code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/QH7p2/)

And if you want to keep the HTML:

```
$(".s").each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

And here's that [code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/X2NyF/).

Answer (score 1):

replaceNode?

http://www.webreference.com/js/column43/replace.html

> The replaceNode method is much more intuitive than the removeNode method. While the removeNode method just removes the specified element and makes its descendents children of their grandfather, the replaceNode method deletes the whole subtree that is rooted at the specified element, and substitutes it with a new element.

```
var msg = "";
function printChildren()  {
   childCount = bodyNode.childNodes.length;
   msg += "childCount = " + childCount;
   for(var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)  {
     msg += "\nchildNodes["+i+"].nodeName = " + bodyNode.childNodes[i].nodeName;
   }
}
printChildren();
msg += "\nReplacing Paragraph 3\n";
var b = document.createTextNode("New Body Page");
var replacedNode = p3Node.replaceNode(b);
msg += "\nreplacedNode.nodeName = " + replacedNode.nodeName;
msg += "\nreplacedNode.childNodes.length = " + replacedNode.childNodes.length;
msg += "\np2Node.nodeName = " + p2Node.nodeName;
printChildren();
alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do:

```
$(".s").remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Will this leave the inner html of the element?

Comment: No, it will not. It just removes the whole thing.

Comment: No, it does not. But I understand the question as this is what it should do. The inner HTML belongs to the instance of the class s.

If this is not the behaviour wanted, please let me know and I will edit.

Comment: How can I make it just remove the html tag? in this case the span tag and leave the text